# Synchronized methods with independent shared variables

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

I recently asked about if synchronized methods in Java shared the same lock key. The answer was yes. But the next thought I had was that this pattern is very restrictive and can cause unnecessary delays. For example suppose we have 2 synchronized methods and each of them process different and independent shared variables. What's the point of locking both methods at the same time if the processing of one variable does not affects the other? Is there a way to deal with this situation?

Comment: There sure is. Even more ways than one. The "Related" block to the right of your screen contains several posts that address those concerns.

Comment: Your question is about the _granularity_ of locking--how much, or how little data is protected by any given lock. The good news is, the granularity is entirely up to you when you write your program. You can use as many or as few different lock objects to protect your data as suits your purpose.

Comment: Re, "What's the point of locking both methods...?" Don't think about "locking methods." Methods do not ever need to be protected by locks. _Data_ need to be protected by locks. Whenever two or more threads can access the same data at the same time, and at least one of them is going to change the data, then the data probably should be protected by a lock.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this class:

```
class C {
    public synchronized void foo(...) { ... }
    public synchronized void bar(...) { ... }
    ...
}
```

And suppose you have:

```
final C c_0 = new C(...);
final C c_1 = new C(...);
```

The fact that `foo()` and `bar()` both are `synchronized` does *not* prevent one thread from calling `c_0.foo(...)` while another thread simultaneously calls `c_1.bar(...)`. In fact, it does not even prevent one thread from calling `c_0.foo(...)` while another thread calls `c_1.foo(...)`.

A so-called "synchronized method"

```
synchronized void foo(...) { ... }
```

Really is just syntactic sugar for this:

```
void foo( ... ) {
    synchronized(this) {
        ...
    }
}
```

So, if one thread calls `c_0.foo()` it's "synchronizing" on the `c_0` instance, and if another thread calls `c_1.foo()`, that thread is synchronizing on the `c_1` instance--a *different* instance.

The `synchronized` keyword on the `foo` and `bar` methods only matters if two different threads both try to operate on the *same instance* at the same time.

Comment: I understand when we have two different but what I mean is related to one object.

Comment: @nonlinearly, If you need more than one lock per object, then don't define `synchronized` methods. Use `synchronized` _blocks_ instead. Synchronized methods are an easy way to handle the simple cases, but the easy way is not always the best way.

Comment: Let me understand what you said. You said that if we use synchronized statement in blocks then we will have different lock key per statement but when we use synchronized in methods then we will have the same one key for each method?

Comment: @nonlinearly, When you write a `synchronized` block, you can choose any object you want to be the lock object. But, when you write a `synchronized` method, then it lock object can only be the instance on which the method is called.